# how to solved no module named 'flask_cors'

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It's currently 3.10.0 version and I've tried sys.path.append, pip install -u flask_cors pip3 install flask_cors, etc. It doesn't work for people who have the same problem as me.

If you move the cursor to flask_cors, the message No module named 'flask_cors' appears.

Also, when I run python app.py, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your IDE using the same python configuration as your CLI where you ran pip install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue some months ago, can you check that all packages are correctly installed with `pip freeze`.

```
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, redirect

try:
    from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin  # The typical way to import flask-cors
except ImportError:
    # Path hack allows examples to be run without installation.
    import os
    parentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    os.sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)
    from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

My requirments for this code :

```
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
```

Comment: it has a same error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fgb\Desktop\FLASK\app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'